# React function not displaying in browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, node-modules

I'm a beginner in react and my terminal keeps displaying the error;
'Hello' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef.

Here's the code below;

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function HelloWorld() {
return (
   <div>
        <Hello/>
   </div>
)}

ReactDom.render (
<HelloWorld/>, document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: Hello is truly not defined, you can't use a component that does not exist

Comment: remove `<Hello/>` add 'Hello'

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't declare `Hello` component. Just change `<Hello/>` to `Hello`.

```
return (
   <div>
      Hello
   </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `<Hello/>`  add  `<h2>Hello</h2>`